# Make installer use local .msi file

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, vdproj

I'm using a Visual Studio Installer Project (.vdproj) to create an installer. When built, it outputs an .msi file and a setup.exe file. When I run the setup.exe, it downloads the .msi from the location specified in the "Installation URL" field in project build properties, and runs it. However, if the PC is offline, the download fails and the install is aborted, although the .msi file is present in the same directory as the .exe file. Is it possible to configure the setup.exe to use the local .msi file if present?

Answer (score 0):

In the Visual Studio Prerequisites you should be able to use the "Download Prerequisites from the same location as my application". This generates a directory (a CD image if you like) that will be used to install the prerequisites. It won't install anything from there unless you build the prerequisites that way. Also, you can't just add a framework with the right name because there's a hash check to ensure that the actual prerequisite redistributable is the correct one.